# Aligning two textviews in a listview

Tags: android, listview, padding

Here's what I have:

[image]

There are options and there are content to every option. Option numbers (A, B, C, D) are in a separate textview and their contents are in a separate textview.

All I'm trying is aligning the option number with the first line of the option content. I tried setting the constant `paddingTop`, but as the number of lines in the option-content changes, it goes out of alignment. Any suggestions upon how to do it?

Here's part of the xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:text="A"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/charcoal"/>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/option_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="100"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="option content...."
        android:textColor="@color/charcoal"/>
```

Can I do it by getting the `paddingTop` of option content dynamically and setting the same padding to the option number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try with below.**

**Replace this in your xml.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/options"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/option_number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="A"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/option_content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:text="option content...."
            android:textColor="@color/charcoal"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**And It's Done.**

Surely it will help you.

Comment: Thanks, the answer is close enough. But whenever there are multiple lines, the option number is a bit lower than the option content. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user5038993 Can u show me screen how much it showing lower while multiple lines. Bcz in my layout i have tried it not showing bit lower even with multiple lines.

Comment: @user5038993 Please accept the answer if it is helpful to you  thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Set android:gravity="top" for option_number TextView android:gravity="top|left" for option_content. Or, User a Relative Layout and use layout_aligntop

Comment: Cannot user the top gravity for option content. It has to float in the middle.

Comment: In that case use a relative layout. use layout_gravity as "center|left" for option content and use layout_alignTop="@id/option_content" for option number

Comment: okay, but then again, I won't be able to use the layout_weight attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/option_number"` on **option_content**

Comment: Thanks for the response, but could we use it with `LinearLayout`?

Comment: My bad. From the code I see, you should be able to change to relativelayout though :)

Comment: Well I have an `ImageView` too down the line. All of them are distributed in proportions using the `layout_weight`. If I user relative layout, I won't be able to use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relative layout instead of linear layout, but you wll have to change your xml a bit. So if you decide to use it you can just set the next property to first TextView

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/option_content"
```

It should help you.

Comment: Using `RelativeLayout` won't allow me to use the `layout_weight`

Comment: @user5038993 If you do require use of LinearLayout only, please specify this in your question, to avoid people submitting answers that do solve your stated question but are not what you are actually seeking.

Answer (score 0):

use: `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Suggestion, can use the following three in combination to easily achieve what you want:
1) CenterVertical
2) ToRightOf
3) RelativeLayout.

e.g:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/options"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:id="@+id/option_number"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/charcoal"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/option_number"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        android:id="@+id/option_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:text="option content...."
        android:textColor="@color/charcoal"/>
```

Comment: what about the `layout_weight` then?

Comment: I can't see why you would need to use "layout_weight" here, if you are using RelativeLayout.  You can just set ``@id/option_content`` to be ``toRightOf`` ``@id/option_number``. (and use a fixed width for ``@id/option_number``)

Comment: Oh im sorry, this will center both textviews vertically in the listview, which will look nice.  If you do want the first text box to align to the _first line of text_ of the second listbox, then in your first textview add ``"android:alignTop="@id/option_content"``. and in your second textview, remove the "toRightOf" and instead just add a ``layout_marginLeft``